# breeze - how to disable ko wrapping?

Tags: breeze

I have a query that is read only and returns a large number of entities.

I do not want change tracking or knockout wrapping for this query.

Is there a way to disable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return results as a projection then Breeze will not try to wrap them. So

```
var q = EntityQuery.from("Customers");
```

will return "wrapped" Customer objects. However if you write

```
var q = EntityQuery.from("Customers").select( "companyName, address, city")
```

then Breeze will return an array of anon "unwrapped" objects each with 3 properties ( "companyName", "address" and "city").

I can't really think of another approach, if you really want entire entities but do not want to Breeze to "wrap" them. But... this does seem like a reasonable request, so please add a [User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions) feature request for an ability to mark a query as "noTracking".  We take these requests seriously.

Comment: Thanks Jay ... I'll add to uservoice.  I saw that projections were not wrapped ... but I'd rather not have to do that .... too much typing.

Comment: I think you could attach a custom `JsonResultsAdapter` to the query ... one that removes the type from the node; that will cause Breeze to treat the query results is data of an anonymous type rather than of an EntityType. It's a hack but it should work.